# Cannot use "storage account" and "file share" that I have created, while doing "docker compose up"

Tags: mysql, azure, docker, docker-compose

I have been following all of the tutorials for using **docker compose** with regards to **azure** and have been running into a problem with regards to volumes.

My docker compose file looks like this :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app-server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/shapeshop?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
      SERVER_PORT: 8080
    networks:
      - backend

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: shapeshop
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - "db-data:/var/lib/mysql"
    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: shapeshopfileshare
      storage_account_name: shapeshopstorageaccount

networks:
  backend:
```

In the above YML file I am defining the **volume** for the mysql container (db) to point to azure artifacts. The tutorials state that I should use "azure_file" as a driver and then create a file share and a storage account.

I created both of these (shapeshopfileshare and shapeshopstorageaccount):

[image]

Now if I log into "az" CLI like so :

```
az login
```

I see my subscription "**shapeShopResourceGroup**"

```
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/8cdb50cb-ede8-4eac-80df-55afadf861cd/resourceGroups/shapeShopResourceGroup",
    "location": "eastus",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "shapeShopResourceGroup",
    "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    },
    "tags": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups"
  },
```

I am also using the "aci" context :

[image]

However when I do **docker compose up** I get this error :

> error: The storage account named **shapeshopstorageaccount** is already
> taken.

This is really frustrating to me because, yes, **shapeshopstorageaccount** DOES EXIST! I created it for ME!

So then, I think somehow my **context** does not associate properly with my **subscription**. So to check I type in :

```
az storage account list
```

...and my **shapeshopstorageaccount** is listed in the returned JSON. So it *seems* like the association between my storage account and subscription exists.

Why is azure (or docker-compose) not associating the declared volume in my YML file with the azure storage that I created??

Comment: I've got to ask:
Why are you not using [external: true](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1) in your compose file since your volume already exists?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to login to Azure Container Registry with `az acr login --name <acrName>` and from the same terminal run the compose command. Check this for more [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose#log-in-to-container-registry).

Alternatively, you might need to include the storage account key in yaml, like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files).

Check also [this](https://docs.docker.com/registry/storage-drivers/azure/), in which I am not sure why variable names are different though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you managed to resolve this,

but ive just come across the same issue. It seems that when docker compose spins up a storage account for you, it uses Storage and not StorageV2.

when i tried to pass it values / keys for a storagev2 it didnt work. I havent tried / checked if i can manually create a storage account thats not v2 right now. but i dont immediately see an option to do that outside of potentially using an ARM template.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34556686)

Answer (score 1):

To use an existing storage account, you must select the same resource group in which this storage account is located during the configuration of the Docker context.

If the context's group doesn't contain the specified storage account, Azure will create it. However, it's important to note that storage account names must be unique throughout Azure, which is the reason for this error.

Answer (score -1):

I think that storage account must be unique globally. The reason for that is that the name becomes part of the URL, let's say
`https://shapeshopstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net`

Try to add oliver_s0mthing to your storage account,probably that is unique name.

Comment: yes I understand it need to be unique globally. Thats not the issue. I am trying to USE the storage account, not CREATE the storage account. In the volumes section in my docker-compose I thought I was just pointing to something that already exists.